# ¿ Problemas con el emulador de visual estudio 2015 al ejecutar app?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Buenas estoy ejecutando un app android y el emulador de visual estudio 2015 no levanta pero al comienzo si levantaba .
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has instalado algo diferente? ¿Has ejecutado Visual Studio como administrador?

Comment: Si se ejecuta como administrador

Comment: ¿Has instalado algo diferente?

Comment: Tienes habilitado Hyper-V?

Comment: Creo que te podrá ayudar éste enlace https://geeks.ms/pcampos/2010/03/11/la-maquina-virtual-no-se-puede-iniciar-porque-el-hypervisor-no-esta-en-ejecucin/

Comment: Gracias Oscar eso era